# $|\sin(nx)| ≤ n|\sin x|$ Proof by induction

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, induction

> Using induction, prove $|\sin(nx)| \le n|\sin x|$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

How I can show that with induction?
Normally , When I make a induction I know for $n$, and I prove for $n+1$. But I can't write $n+1$ in this question. If I write $n+1$, formula change like this: $|\sin((n+1)x)| \le (n+1)|\sin x|$ for $n+1$, This new formula doesn't include $n$.

What should I do in such cases?

Comment: Indeed a duplicate, but I suggest to try it yourself. Write $\sin((n+1)x)=\sin(nx+x)$ and use the formula $\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For induction step we can use that

$$|\sin ((n+1)x)|=|\sin(nx+x)|=|\sin(nx)\cos x+\sin x\cos(nx)|$$

$$\le |\sin(nx)\cos x|+|\sin x\cos(nx)|\le n|\sin x|+|\sin x|=(n+1)|\sin x|$$